# TeXnicCenter freezes on Build

Tags: texniccenter

TeXnicCenter used to work perfectly with Windows on my system.

However since this morning (I made no changes to my system in the meantime) when I try to build a project or file, TeXnicCenter freezes for minutes together and goes into 'Not responding' mode. But after a while, it does compile - which I know by the green color on the taskbar icon. But it takes aeons to do so.

Is there any way this can be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried to compile manually from command line to see if that yields more information?

Comment: Usually a long delay means that MikTeX is loading something off the internet.  Try updating more often.

Comment: @siracusa No, I haven't. But today, it's working fine. Very temperamental!! :)

Comment: @JohnKormylo made a good point here. If TeXnicCenter hangs whenever you are using a new package but only hangs on the first compilation run of your document, it's very likely that it's MiKTeX installing packages behind the scenes which is causing the frozen GUI. That would also explain why you see this behaviour only occasionally.

Comment: @siracusa That wasn't the case here. No new packages, and it was the umpteenth compilation run. That's what got me confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you described is not caused by TeXnicCenter, it is caused by your used MiKTeX distribution (you did not mention it, but for me it seems to be clear you are using MiKTeX and not TeX Live).

It seems you have installed a **basic** MiKTeX version.  That means that **not** the compete MiKTeX is installed, **only a part** of it, containing the most important packages.

That causes problems if your TeX code uses an package that is not yet installed, so MiKTeX tries to download and install the missing package(s) on the fly.  In this time TeXnicCenter is blocked (freezed, no return message) because it get no positive return code from MIKTeX that the compilation has ended ...

Comment: Yes, I do have MiKTeX :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in the off-chance that you use Dropbox or another sync client for the directory where your .tex files are located: TeXnicCenter is known to have problems with Dropbox ([see this user report for more](https://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/user-reports/1498/)). A solution appears to be to temporarily pause syncing.